# Problems translating the default "Name" field on tags

Tags: localization, tags

I'm building a multi-lingual site (english and spanish) and I have a news section with entries that have a "tags" field attached.

I've marked this field as "translatable" in the CP.

But, when I've added a tag to an entry, double clicking it reveals the pop-up field editor where I can switch between locales as expected (see screenshot). But I can't enter different values for "Name" in each locale. It behaves like a  non-translatable field where changing the value in one locale changes it for all the others.

[image]

Setting my "tags" field as translatable in the CP seems to allow me to assign different tags to the entry for each locale, but that's not what I want. What I want is to have an entry's tags persist across locales, but be translated into their appropriate language.

Is the default "Name" field for tags translatable? How should I be setting this up to get the behavior I want?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this is indeed the case (as of  2.1.2564). I don't know if it's intended behaviour or a bug, but I would wager the former.  I seem to recall somewhere learning that P&T made an explicit decision to not have tag Names be translatable.

As a workaround you could consider a tag custom field with a "translatable label" that you fill in for each language? Seems a bit lame. I'd probably opt for simply making the field itself translatable, and then binding separate tags for each language.

Comment: Thanks John. I'll probably go in the direction of creating separate tags for each language.